# can i store datatable for the further refinement

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a datatable with the results i just want to refine the results using this datatable... i am trying to do it but this datatable is distroyed each time page is refreshed......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the datatable in a session variable or cache

```
Cache.Insert("MyData1", datatable)
```

when the the page loads again you can check to see of the cache value is not equal to null.  If its not you can use the value again.

ie.

```
Datatable Source;
Source = (Datatable)Cache["MyData1"];
```

Comment: but using cache for a large datatable is a good option.. is it not any bad effect on my application...........

Answer (score 1):

*News flash:* The web is stateless!

You would do well to look up "[State management in ASP.NET](http://www.google.com/search?q=state+management+in+ASP.NET)".